# Groovy xml to map with duplicate keys

Tags: xml, dictionary, groovy

I need to use groovy to convert a XML with the same keys

```
 <Root>
    <firstname>abc </firstname>
    <firstname>bcd </firstname>
    <lastname>abf </lastname>     
</Root>
```

To map, I'd expect something like :

```
[firstname:{"abc , bcd"} , lastname:"abf"]
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Everyone has their needs, and we're not judgemental here. Good for you. That said, it would help all of us a lot if you shared what you've done so far with us. XML is extremely simple to work with in Groovy, and there's a multitude of online resources describing how to do just that

Comment: At the moment, i convert my xml like this  : _xml.children().collectEntries { 
        [ it.name(), it.childNodes() ? convertToMap(it) : it.text() ] }

Comment: Are you expecting `[firstname: "abc", lastname: "bcd, abf"]` or should your XML structure show two `<firstname>` elements instead of two `<lastname>`?

Comment: It was a mistake in my  XML, i expected `[firstname:"abc , bcd" , lastname:"abf"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably loads of ways to do this.  Assuming your xml is only one level deep (as in your example), you could do:

```
def xml = '''<Root>
    <firstname>abc </firstname>
    <firstname>bcd </firstname>
    <lastname>abf </lastname>     
</Root>'''

new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
    .children()
    .groupBy { it.name() }
    .collectEntries { k, v -> [k, v*.text()*.trim().join(', ')] }
```

If your xml is deeper, then the problem rapidly becomes non-trivial, and you will have to make some decisions about what you are going to do...  XML can hold more data than a map

#### Edit

So you can try something like this for more arbitrary processing:

Given the xml in the form:

```
def xml = '''<Root>
    <firstname>abc </firstname>
    <firstname>bcd </firstname>
    <lastname>abf </lastname>  
    <adresse> <ville>aaa</ville><ville>eeee</ville><pays>ffff</pays></adresse>   
</Root>'''
```

Then processing it with:

```
new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml).with { node ->
    node.children()
        .groupBy { it.name() }
        .collectEntries { k, v ->
            [k, v.any { it.children().size() } ?
                    v.collect(owner) :
                    v*.text()*.trim().join(', ')]
        }
}
```

Should give you the output:

```
['firstname':'abc, bcd', 'lastname':'abf', 'adresse':[['ville':'aaa, eeee', 'pays':'ffff']]]
```

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates for your answers, my xml can have more than one level like this :   `<Root>
    <firstname>abc </firstname>
    <firstname>bcd </firstname>
    <lastname>abf </lastname> 
     <adresse> <ville>eee</ville><pays>ffff</pays></adresse>
</Root>`

Comment: So what should happen in that situation?

Comment: `[firstname:"abc , bcd" , lastname:"abf", adresse:[ville:"eee" , pays:"ffff"]]`

Comment: Updated answer, but it's getting a bit illegible ;-)

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.